# how to sum 2 rows php mysql

Tags: php, sum

my mysql db

```
ID platos mhkos 
1    22    33
2    15   12
```

search by ID and result = platos + mhkos how to ?

my code is

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/hlios.php'); ?>
<?php echo $row_test['platos']; ?>+ <?php echo $row_test['mhkos']; ?>

= <?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_test = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['client_id'])) {
  $colname_test = $_GET['client_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_hlios, $hlios);
$query_test = sprintf("SELECT * FROM carpets_1 WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_test, "int"));
$test = mysql_query($query_test, $hlios) or die(mysql_error());
$row_test = mysql_fetch_assoc($test);
$totalRows_test = mysql_num_rows($test);


mysql_free_result($test);
?>
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Would you please give the example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you mean how to get the sum of two columns? If yes, please edit the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though what the OP means is sum of two COLUMNS in one ROW.

```
SELECT platos + mhkos AS totals FROM carpets_1 WHERE id = %s
```

If the OP wants sum of all columns and rows it would be

```
SELECT sum(platos) as totalPlatos, sum(mhkos) as totalMhkos FROM carpets_1
```

The question does seem quite confusing, though. Hence me leaning toward the initial two columns and one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT platos + mhkos AS totals FROM carpets_1 WHERE id = %s
```

Comment: This will only sum a row, not 2 rows. CMIIW.

Comment: Please edit your question then and make it clearer what you are trying to sum; and given the data you provide, give the answer to that sum as well.